# Expiring page cache from a different view controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm a bit of a rails noob and have this situation. I have a model: categories. These categories are edited through the fantastic activeadmin.

Now, I'm building this rails app as a backend for a iOS app. As a result, these categories will be quered a lot and thus I want to cache them. But here is the problem: I need to find a way to clear the cache when a category is added or edited through activeadmin.

I'm using page caching: `caches_page :index` in the categories view controller `categories_controller.rb`

I did some digging and it looks like ActiveAdmin does not call the create method in my controller. It actually has it's own create method in `app/admin/categories.rb`

I need to find a way to send a message from the admin's create method to the view controller so I can expire the cache. How do I do this? Is this is a bad approach and I'm doing this horribly wrong?

Thanks,

-David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for you is sweepers! http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers